# Can I get a Private Pilot's License if I have controllable ADD and just send a waiver to my doctor?

Tags: faa, medical

Hello I am a fan of aviation and would love to be a private pilot, but I have ADD that is controllable. I can control my ADD and I'm cancelling my medications. Can I get a medical certificate if I just send a waiver from my doctor to the AME or FAA? Thanks for the help

Comment: Although you're not reapplying [this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/30939/1696) does address applying for a medical with history of ADD.

Comment: See [this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12747/62) and [the FAA's examination requirements](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/media/adhdevalspecs.pdf). Unfortunately, once you've been diagnosed with AD(H)D it becomes quite difficult to get a medical, even if you're now off meds. Ideally you should have a consultation only - don't apply for the actual medical! - with an experienced AME who's dealt with similar cases before. A sport pilot license could be another option; there's no medical required.

Comment: Your doctor cannot issue waivers, only letters concerning your treatment. Getting a waiver is done through the FAA and as Pondlife said, is very difficult even after discontinuing medication.

Comment: Yes, by going through the proper steps you might get a medical. Be sure you don't mistake "difficult" for "impossible". If you are motivated and stick with it you may very well be able to get a medical if you are no longer taking medication despite a past diagnosis.

Comment: Pond life is right, consultation only cuz if you are denied you can never go LSA, which is where you,re headed.